# Pointer is modified unexpectedly

Tags: c++, pointers, red-black-tree

I'm coding the Red-Black-Tree by following *Introduction to Algorithms*. And when it comes to the right-rotate function, one of my pointer was modified unexpectedly.

```
 void RBTree::RightRotate(pNode &z)
 {
    pNode l=z->lChild;
    z->lChild = l->rChild;      //link z->l-r to z as a lChild
    if(l->rChild != nil)        
        l->rChild->p = z;       
    l->p = z->p;                //when pass the tree's root as parameter
                                //z,after executing this line, z was 
                                //modified to pointing to nil
                                //(known from debug window), why?
    if(z->p == nil)             
        root = l;
    else if (z == z->p->lChild)
        z->p->lChild = l;
    else
        z->p->rChild = l;
    l->rChild=z;
    z->p=l;
 }
```

And just as  *Introduction to Algorithms* goes, I set `nil` pointer in my class.
Since only when root was passed as parameter `z` can  cause this problem, I defer it's something wrong with `nil` and `root`.The following is the whole code.
:

```
    #include 
    #include 
    #include       
    #define RED 1
    #define BLACK 0
    using namespace std;
    typedef struct Node
    {
        int color, val;
        struct Node* lChild, *rChild, *p;
        Node(int val_, struct Node* tmp)   
              {color=RED, val=val_,lChild=rChild=p=tmp;}
        Node(){color=BLACK, val=0,lChild=rChild=p=NULL;}
    }Node,*pNode;

    class RBTree
    {
    public:
        RBTree()
        {
            root=NULL;
        }
        ~RBTree()
        {
            Free_(root);
        }
        void Free_(pNode p)
        {
            if(p!=NULL)
            {
                Free_(p->lChild);
                Free_(p->rChild);
                delete(p);
                p=NULL;
            }
        }
        pNode FindMin() const
        {
            pNode p=root;
            if (p)
                while(p->lChild)
                    p=p->lChild;
            return p;
        }
        pNode FindMax() const
        {
            pNode p=root;
            if (p)
                while(p->rChild)
                    p=p->rChild;
            return p;
        }
        void Print(pNode p, int n) const
        {
            if(!p)
                return;
            Print(p->rChild,n+2);
            for(int i=0;ivalcolor==1)?"R":"B")lChild,n+2);
        }
        pNode Root() {return root;}
        void Insert(int const& val_);
        void InsertFixup(pNode &z);
        void LeftRotate(pNode &p);
        void RightRotate(pNode &p);
        pNode Search(pNode const &p, int x) const;
        void  Delete(pNode &p, int x);

    private:
        pNode root;
        static pNode nil;
    };

    pNode RBTree::nil = new Node();

    /*
    Inserting pipiline:
    Insert node into RBTree, then fixup.
    In the fixup procedure , rotate may be called
     */

    void RBTree::InsertFixup(pNode &z)
    {
        while (z->p->color == RED)
        {
            pNode y;
            if (z->p == z->p->p->lChild)
            {
                y=z->p->p->rChild;
                if(y->color == RED)
                {
                    z->p->color = BLACK;
                    y->color = BLACK;
                    z->p->p->color = RED;
                    z = z->p->p;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(z==z->p->rChild)
                    {
                        z = z->p;
                        LeftRotate(z);
                    }
                    z->p->color = BLACK;
                    z->p->p->color = RED;
                    RightRotate(z->p->p);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                y=z->p->p->lChild;
                if(y->color == RED)
                {
                    z->p->color = BLACK;
                    y->color = BLACK;
                    z->p->p->color = RED;
                    z=z->p->p;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(z==z->p->lChild)
                    {
                        z = z->p;
                        RightRotate(z);
                    }
                    z->p->color = BLACK;
                    z->p->p->color = RED;
                    LeftRotate(z->p->p);
                }
            }
        }
        root->color = BLACK;
    }
    void RBTree::Insert(int const &val_)
    {
        pNode z=new Node(val_, nil);            //set val, lChild, rChild, p to NULL, color to RED
        pNode x = root;
        pNode pre = nil;
        if(NULL == root)
            root = z;
        else
        {
            while (x!=nil)
            {
                pre=x;
                x=(x->valrChild:x->lChild;
            }
            z->p = pre;
            if (z->val val)
                pre->lChild = z;
            else
                pre->rChild = z;
        }
        InsertFixup(z);
    }

    //left-rotate
    //denote z, z's rChild == r
    //parent changed: z, r, r's lChild
    //child chagend:  z->rChild, r->lChild, z->p->lChild/rChild
    void RBTree::LeftRotate(pNode &z)
    {
        pNode r=z->rChild;
        z->rChild = r->lChild;      //link p->r-l to p as a r
        if(r->lChild != nil)
            r->lChild->p = z;
        r->p = z->p;
        if(z->p == nil)
            root = r;
        else if (z == z->p->lChild)
            z->p->lChild = r;
        else
            z->p->rChild = r;

        r->lChild=z;
        z->p=r;
    }
    // right-rotate
    void RBTree::RightRotate(pNode &z)
    {
        pNode l=z->lChild;
        z->lChild = l->rChild;      //link p->l-r to p as a l
        if(l->rChild != nil)
            l->rChild->p = z;
        l->p = z->p;
        if(z->p == nil)             //link parent from top to bottom
            root = l;
        else if (z == z->p->lChild)
            z->p->lChild = l;
        else
            z->p->rChild = l;
        l->rChild=z;
        z->p=l;
    }
    int main()
    {
        int a[9] = {11, 2, 14, 1, 7, 15, 5, 8, 4};
        RBTree tr;
        for(int i=0;i
```

Am I using nil in a  wrong way? 
Thanks.

Comment: A compilable test case would be really nice. At the very least, you should show the definition of `Node` and the calls that lead to `RightRotate`. This is most likely some aliasing issue.

Comment: I posted the whole program, but it seems something was wrong with '<' and line after that on the page, can you help correct the style? @SebastianRedl

Answer (score 1):

Nill is not a C++ expression. However some environments might include it, just using it as an alias for `NULL` or `0`. If you use C++11, I would recommend `nullptr`

Try to have a look whether

`l->p` < `z` && `z`< `l->p` + `sizeof(z)`

If that is the case, you are assigning to `z`.

Comment: I set a `count` variable ,and added *cout<<z->val<<endl<<count++<<endl;* before and after that line.The output is 11 and 0. So it really changed. No overload, and I think no multithreaded operaiton either. Really confused.

Comment: @ArthurTian Mhm maybe you could try getting the address of `l->p` and the address of `z`. If   `l->p` <  `z` < `l->p` + `sizeof(z)` . This might also cause the address to change.

Comment: @ArturTian I've changed my answer to reflect the solution. I'm not aware of the context well enough to know whether is it's an error of the book.

Comment: How can I make some efforts to avoid this situation, please?And what's the reason behind this ? Isn't the assignment be operated only on the object `l` ?Many thanks if more advice.

Comment: Well you could check if they point to the same thing in advance. However, what you should do if this is the case, entirely depends on what you aim to achieve with the code.

Comment: Finally, with the help of my friend, I found it's a problem with the reference parameter. Anyway, many thanks.